# Discord self bot slow

Tags: discord

```
from discord.ext.commands import Bot
from discord.ext import commands
import asyncio

#TOKEN
TOKEN = "token"

client = discord.Client()
b = Bot(command_prefix = "!")

@b.event
async def on_ready():
    print("on")

@b.event
async def on_message(message):
    if "here" in message.content: 
        try:
            await message.author.dm_channel.send("Message I choose")
        except:
            print('The DM could not be send due to privacy permissions')

b.run(TOKEN, bot = False)
```

---

So I have this self bot in discord. Basically it just checks when a person in a server says "@here" it will auto dm them with the message I choose as quick as possible. I would just like to know how would I make this self bot check if the person said  that said @here faster.

Comment: What do you mean by "faster"?

Comment: A way to check the message 2x the speed instead of a if statement.

Comment: As far as I know, you won't get any better than O(n) time complexity for searching a string (which your code has). Also, [self-botting is forbidden and can result in account termination](https://support.discord.com/hc/en-us/articles/115002192352-Automated-user-accounts-self-bots-).